# Node.js proxy file uploading

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, meanjs

I have a MEAN.js application in which I use https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload to handle angular file uploads to server. What I want to do is receive the files on the server, and then pipe them to another server where I would like to use a writeStream to write them.

Is there a way I can do this?

```
ar data = {
    file : {
        buffer:req.files.file.buffer,
        filename : req.files.file.name,
        content_type : 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    options : {
        operation : 'Content',
        source : req.body.source
    }
};
needle.post(config.vdnURL,data,{ multipart:true},function(error, response) {
```

on the other server which is supposed to receive the file and write it to disk, I do the following

```
mkdirp(config.winUploadPath+ req.body.options.source + '/'+ req.body.options.operation +'/', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {

            fs.writeFile(config.winUploadPath + req.body.options.source + '/'+ req.body.options.operation +'/' + req.files.file.name, req.files.file.buffer, function (uploadError) {
                if (uploadError) {
                    console.log('Got upload error ', uploadError);
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: 'Error occurred while uploading profile picture'
                    });
                } else {

                    res.status(200).send({
                        message: 'Upload successful',
                        url: req.body.options.source + '/'+ req.body.options.operation +'/' + req.files.file.name
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem arises when the file size exceeds a couple of MB's (>3-4MB). Files don't get written at all and the second server shows

`POST / -- ms --` with no file written.

Hence I thought its a streaming problem. Any help on how maybe I can solve it will be greatly appreciated.